# why use traits while i can put code in file

Tags: php, traits

Traits are a mechanism for code reuse in single inheritance languages such as PHP. A Trait is intended to reduce some limitations of single inheritance by enabling a developer to reuse sets of methods freely in several independent classes living in different class hierarchies. The semantics of the combination of Traits and classes is defined in a way which reduces complexity, and avoids the typical problems associated with multiple inheritance

Why should I use trait while I can put the code in a file and call whenever I want?

Comment: Do what ever works for you, that's the beauty of code.

Comment: Question is similar to - why use IDE, I can write code in Notepad.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question is not really appropriate for SO, as it is very broad and answers will be opinion-based. SO is for specific problems about programming, usually with some code involved. Please have a look at the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) guides for more info.